# Redirect JSON index files in sub dirs to PHP controller

Tags: php, json, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm trying to figure out a way to make it so that if I have a directory that contains a JSON file as its index (e.g. `index.json`) that I can have it so that when someone visits that directory the `index.json` is passed to a "controller" PHP file outside of that directory that decodes the JSON and generates a page based on it. Is this possible somehow via .htaccess and/or PHP without needing to have multiple copies of the "controller" PHP file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try do so something like this using mod_rewrite. Say your php contoller is here: `/path/to/json.php`, you'd use these rules

```
RewriteEngine On

# Check if request is for a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

# Check if there's an index.json file in that directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.json -f

# Pass the request to the controller
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /path/to/json.php?file=$1/index.json [L]
```

The rule itself can be tweaked to fit how your controller works. You could not pass a query string at all if your json.php controller can look at the requested URI, and look for the index.json file by itself.

Comment: Man that solution is perfect—simple and powerful. I tested it and it works. TY! Is it possible to make it so that it resolves like that internally but maintains the original directory as the visible URL in the address bar?

Comment: It maintains orig dir as the visible URL as long as the path is relative. Again—this is ace.